# Json - iPhone app: uitableview and uiwebview

Tags: iphone, json, uitableview, uiwebview

I am quite new to Xcode and Json.

In my app, I have navigation through pages via tableviews (drill down). What I want to do now, is to use Json to create my tableviews and then when I select a cell in the uitableview, it will go to a website through the next page via a uiwebview.

How will I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Parse your j[son using a parser](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/)
2. Create the parsed response as a data model for table view. You can use a Dictionary/array to keep things simple
3. Implement the tableview delegate methods and get the selected index
4. On didselectatrowindex method you create a new view, fetch the url from your model and load it into the webview.

I could write some code but thats really too much you are asking for. If you get stuck in any of the steps above, do leave a comment. I will be glad to help you out.

Comment: I think I know how to do step 1 and step 4 as I seem to have done the didselectatrowindex before when I'm doing drilldowns. Can you elaborate step 2 and 3 and also, how can I fetch the url from my modal for step 4. Thanks. (P.S. I have completed that Json Tutorial before. Would it be easier if I were to build on from what I have from that tutorial?)

Comment: From where are you populating your table view data. That is the data model for your app.

Comment: Is it similar to this tutorial? http://iphonedevelopertips.com/networking/iphone-json-flickr-tutorial-part-1.html